# how to mock a file object in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, mocking, magicmock

In python2 I have this in my test method:

```py
mock_file = MagicMock(spec=file)
```

I'm moving to python3, and I can't figure out how to do a similar mock. I've tried:

```py
from io import IOBase
mock_file = MagicMock(spec=IOBase)

mock_file = create_autospec(IOBase)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IOBase` does not implement crucial file methods such as `read` and `write` and is therefore usually unsuitable as a spec to create a mocked file object with. Depending on whether you want to mock a raw stream, a binary file or a text file, you can use `RawIOBase`, `BufferedIOBase` or `TextIOBase` as a spec instead:

```
from io import BufferedIOBase
mock_file = MagicMock(spec=BufferedIOBase)
```